# Can Erlang's mod_esi redirect?

Tags: erlang, inets

I'm trying to learn doing web application development in Erlang, just using the standard library's inets modules at this stage.

The snag I've hit is that I want to validate the data from a post query, and then either redirect back to the form page with error messages or to a welcome page.

Basically, what I need to do is get a return header which looks like

```
HTTP/1.1 303 OK
Location: /form.html
...
```

While `mod_esi:deliver/2` lets me add header `key: value` fields, I don't see how I can replace the default

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
```

With `HTTP/1.1 303 OK` to do a redirect.

While I'm sure cowboy, elli, etc can do this easily, before learning a third-party application I was wondering if `mod_esi` or other inets modules can do this.

What I have is a module called handler which has a function `form/3` (adhering to http://erlang.org/doc/man/mod_esi.html#Module:Function-3) which returns http://erlang.org/doc/man/mod_esi.html#deliver-2 as required.

Answer (score 1):

If you include a `Location` header, `mod_esi` should automatically set the status to `302`.  If you want to set the status to something else, you can use the `Status` header.  e.g. `Status: 303 See Other`.  (This is how CGI works too.)